# unexpected lines showing only on smartphone browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to code a simple and clean coded website (I'm a beginner) and I'm using waves from https://getwaves.io/ to improve the design. I'm separating each section/div with a simple wave to separate them and each of them has a different color (of course, what would be the point of putting a wave then...)

When I'm looking at the result on my laptop with Safari, Chrome and Firefox: no problem at all.

On my iPhone btw, on both Safari and Chrome, the first separation looks fine, but all the others look separated from the upper section by a thin horizontal line and I really don't get why.

Here are some screenshots to explain better, I'll provide code below.

[image]

[image]

The test site if you want to see by yourself either on laptop (no problem) or smartphone (problem):  https://www.pierreherbillon.com/perseus/

Here's the code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Prompt:wght@100;300;900&display=swap');


body,html{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h4 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size: 1.25rem;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}


a {
    font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 1.7em;
}


    .section{
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 100vh;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #section0 {
        background-color: #d4b4b4;
    }
    #section1 {
        background-color: #d7d7d7;
    }
    #section2 {
        background-color: #474747;
    }
    #section3 {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
    #section4 {
        background-color: #d4b4b4;
    }
    #section-footer {
        background-color: #383838;
    }
```

```html
<div class="section" id="section0">
    <nav>
        <!-- here is the code of the navbar, i don't yhink it is relevant for this matter -->
    </nav>
        <img class="logo" src="pegasus-logo2.png" alt="logo" width="300px" />
        <h1>PERSEUS</h1><br><br><h4 style="letter-spacing: 10px; font-family: 'Prompt', sans-serif; font-weight: 100;">Un site pour vous ?</h4>
</div>
<!-- SECTION 1 -->
<div class="section" id="section1">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 192"><path fill="#d4b4b4" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,0L120,26.7C240,53,480,107,720,138.7C960,171,1200,181,1320,186.7L1440,192L1440,0L1320,0C1200,0,960,0,720,0C480,0,240,0,120,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
    <div class="rows">
        <div class="column1">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Section 1</h2><br>
            <p>
                <!-- SOME TEXT HERE -->
            </p><br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- SECTION 2 -->
<div class="section" id="section2">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 192"><path fill="#d7d7d7" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,0L120,26.7C240,53,480,107,720,138.7C960,171,1200,181,1320,186.7L1440,192L1440,0L1320,0C1200,0,960,0,720,0C480,0,240,0,120,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
    <div class="rows">
        <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #f0f0f0;">Section 2</h2><br>
        <div class="column2">
            <p style="color: #f0f0f0;">
                <!-- SOME TEXT HERE TOO -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column2">
            <p style="color: #f0f0f0;">
                <!-- SOME TEXT HERE TOO -->
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- SECTION 3 -->
<div class="section" id="section3">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 192"><path fill="#474747" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,0L120,26.7C240,53,480,107,720,138.7C960,171,1200,181,1320,186.7L1440,192L1440,0L1320,0C1200,0,960,0,720,0C480,0,240,0,120,0L0,0Z"></path></svg>
    <div class="rows">
        <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #565656;">Section 3</h2><br>
        <div class="column3">
            <p style="color: #565656;">
                <!-- SOME TEXT AGAIN -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column3">
            <p style="color: #565656;">
                <!-- SOME TEXT AGAIN -->
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column3">
            <p style="color: #565656;">
                <!-- SOME TEXT AGAIN -->
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On my phone looks ok - Android 11, Chrome browser.

Comment: Thank you Karol. So the problem would maybe occur only on iphones ?
I took the screenshot from Chrome, but it looks the same on Safari.

Comment: I know that safari can cause a lot of issues if it comes to styling - specially older versions, but since it doesn't work properly on Chrome either I don't know what may cause this issue.

Comment: Have you tried a negative top margin to overlap and remove line? `.section{ margin-top: -5px; }`